# Intellij private docker registry

Tags: intellij-idea, private, docker-registry

After reinstalling Windows I installed latest IntelliJ IDEA 2021.3 (Ultimate Edition) when I tried to add my private docker registry... I did get three option and none of them works. ([IntelliJ support](https://www.jetbrains.com/help/idea/settings-docker-registry.html))

Select one of the available public Docker registries:

- Docker Hub: registry.hub.docker.com
- GitLab: gitlab.com
- JetBrains Space: your instance of Space

I cant say if this is a bug from there side or not... or if there is some setting I have to change... so my workaround for now is a zip file with this structure.

```
settig.zip
  /IntelliJ IDEA Global Settings
  /options
    /docker-registry.xml
```

IntelliJ IDEA Global Settings is an empty file

docker-registry.xml simple xml file with this structure

```
<application>
  <component name="DockerRegistry">
    <DockerRegistry>
      <option name="address" value="private.registry.com" />
      <option name="name" value="Name" />
      <option name="username" value="Username" />
    </DockerRegistry>
  </component>
</application>
```

Then import settings from a ZIP archive

1. Call File | Manage IDE Settings | Import Settings from the main menu.
2. Select the ZIP archive that contains your settings in the dialog that opens.
3. Select the settings you want to apply in the Select Components to Import dialog that opens and click OK.

anyone knows what can be wrong or are the more ppl out there with this problem?

if you try this remember to backup your save registry's as how import works.

Answer (score 1):

Custom registries are not yet supported. You can vote for implementation at https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/IDEA-282438

Comment: it did work great before the last update...

Comment: This was supported and worked fine for me previously - latest update has taken this away

Comment: We brought the function back in 2022.1 EAP 3. It will be released soon at [EAP page](https://www.jetbrains.com/idea/nextversion/)